# function parameter errors in Standard ML

Tags: sml, ml

I am trying to implement a function treeToString that uses this data type:

```
datatype Tree = LEAF of string | NODE of Tree list;
```

and this tree:

```
val L1a = LEAF "a"
val L1b = LEAF "b"
val L1c = LEAF "c"
val L2a = NODE [L1a, L1b, L1c]
val L2b = NODE [L1b, L1c, L1a]
val L3 = NODE [L2a, L2b, L1a, L1b]
val L4 = NODE [L1c, L1b, L3]
val L5 = NODE [L4]
```

The function takes an argument like `treeToString L5` which will output the string `((cb((abc)(bca)ab)))`

The problem is I cannot figure out the correct way to differentiate between when the function takes in a LEAF or a NODE type. I wrote the code below to try and test this but I am getting errors. Anyone know the syntax in order to get this to work? Once I get the parameters down, the actual recursion should be easy.

```
(* treeToString *)
fun treeToString(LEAF str) = str
|   treeToString(NODE h::t) = 
    h;
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is what I used to get it working. Just needed to add parenthesis around my arguments

```
fun treeToString f Node = let
    fun helperFun (LEAF(v)) = [f v]
    |   helperFun (NODE(h::t)) = ["("] @ List.concat (map helperFun(h::t)) @ [")"]
    in
        String.concat(helperFun Node)
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
|   treeToString(NODE h::t) = ...
```

To this:

```
  | treeToString (NODE (h::t)) = ...
```

The reason is that `(NODE h::t)` can be interpreted as either `((NODE h)::t)` (where `NODE h` is the first item in a list of NODE's) or as `(NODE (h::t))`, which is what you want.